# disable thumbnail creating or move thumbnail directory with Fedora

Tags: gnome, fedora, thumbnails

I'm on a shared system and have very little space my home directory; can I move the .thumbnails folder somewhere, or disable thumbnail creation?  I notice most when I use Eye of Gnome to view many images in series.

Comment: Presumably the images are remote (if they are local you could create more home directory space by moving some to external storage) -- have you set Nautilus to only use thumbnails for local folders and only for small files?

Comment: Does setting this in nautilus help anything?  I never open nautilus, just eye of gnome.

Comment: Probably not if you *never* use nautilus (e.g. folder viewer). There is a range of issues about whether any fix should be to not have any thumbnails (the 'map to null' class of solution), not allow more thumbnails (the `chmod` class of solutions), prevent formation via `gconf`, select thumbnail creation per app, or discard thumbnails at the end of a session. This was discussed in detail in relation to eog in [https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/eog/+bug/255030](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/eog/+bug/255030) and it may be helpful to read that discussion and review the patch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try redirecting ~/.thumbnails or its subfolders to /dev/null (works with subfolders at least):

rm -rf ~/.thumbnails

ln -s /dev/null ~/.thumbnails

Comment: Nice, I had just linked it to /tmp/.thumbnails, /dev/null was too dark and scary last year when I asked this.

Comment: @Thomas: "dark and scary" was funny! But seriously, if you link anywhere inside `/tmp`, be a good citizen and (pre-)append your user name, so you don't monopolize the solution: `/tmp/$USER/thumbnails`. Also, No need to be hidden. And some systems `/tmp` is discarted on every reboot, so you might need to re-create that dir in `~/.profile`